# Firebird 2.5 Page size affecting query speed in QLikview and Excel via ODBC

Tags: vba, odbc, oledb, firebird, qlikview

I've inherited a Firebird DB in my new job, and we've had some trouble doing ETL on some large tables (some have 200+ fields and >2Mill rows).

The techy guys increased the Fbird page size from 8k to 16k and this dramatically increased the return speed in Qlikview (up to x10 faster), from which most of the reports are run...however, the same day a small suite of daily legacy reports in which Excel uses odbc or oledb to connect to firebird (e.g.runs an SQL script, and pastes the records into a workbook) suddenly started taking 30+ minutes when they previously ran in 5 mins.

I have checked and nothing else changed in those reports, so the paging must be the reason.

I have googled and read lots of Firebird FAQ's etc and can't see aything about oledb being slower at higher page sizes...

I am not expecting a direct answer here, but I would like advice and hints on where to investigate next, my ideal outcone would be a tweak to these legacy odbc/OLEDB connections to speed these reports back up...  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Page size difference do not affect the access libraries, its effects are fully internal to the Firebird server. More likely the problem is due to the optimizer now choosing a different (and in this case: wrong) access path, or the legacy reports are enforcing their own plans that are now inefficient.

Comment: I suggest you take this question to the Firebird-support mailinglist. As you indicate you don't expect a direct answer but some advice or hints, unfortunately StackOverflow is not really suited for this type of questions.

Comment: thanks. i'll find the mailing list.

Comment: Mabye you can add some indexes or optimize the Excel or other long running queries. I guess the increase of page size is an overhead for queries with small resultsets..